# how to horizontally translate specific nodes based on scroll changed in a WPF treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Here is xaml code that builds up a tree with horizontal nodes for me.

```
<ResourceDictionary 
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BlogSample">

 <local:HorzLineConv x:Key="horzLineConv"/>
 <local:VertLineConv x:Key="vertLineConv"/>

<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem" x:Key="GraphStyle">
<Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem">
      <Grid> <!-- Main Grid-->
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
          <!-- Horizontal line-->
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
          <!--The top row contains the item's content.-->
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          <!-- Item presenter(children) -->
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0"> <!-- Horizontal line grid -->
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

          <!-- Horizontal line to the left -->
          <Rectangle  Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      Stroke="Black" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
            <Rectangle.Height>
              <Binding  Mode="OneWay"
                        Converter="{StaticResource horzLineConv}"
                        ConverterParameter="left" 
                        RelativeSource="{RelativeSource
                            AncestorLevel=1,
                            AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}"/>
            </Rectangle.Height>
          </Rectangle>

          <!-- Horizontal line to the right -->
          <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                     Stroke="Black"
                     SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
            <Rectangle.Height>
              <Binding Mode="OneWay" 
                Converter="{StaticResource horzLineConv}" 
                ConverterParameter="right" 
                RelativeSource="{RelativeSource 
                  AncestorLevel=1, 
                  AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}"/>
            </Rectangle.Height>
          </Rectangle>
        </Grid> <!-- End of Horizontal line grid -->

        <Grid Grid.Row="1"> <!-- Header grid -->
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/><!-- Vert. line above node  -->
              <RowDefinition Height="*"/>   <!-- Header -->
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/><!-- Vert line below node   -->
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <!-- Vertical line above node -->
          <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" 
                     Height="10" Stroke="Black" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
            <Rectangle.Width>
              <Binding Mode="OneWay" 
                Converter="{StaticResource vertLineConv}" 
                ConverterParameter="top" 
                RelativeSource=
                  "{RelativeSource AncestorLevel=1, 
                                   AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}"/>
            </Rectangle.Width>
          </Rectangle>

          <!-- Header -->
          <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" ContentSource="Header" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

          <!-- Vertical line below node -->
          <Rectangle Grid.Row="2"  Height="10" Stroke="Black" 
            SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
            <Rectangle.Width>
              <Binding Mode="OneWay" 
                Converter="{StaticResource vertLineConv}" 
                ConverterParameter="bottom" 
                RelativeSource=
                  "{RelativeSource  AncestorLevel=1, 
                                    AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}"/>
            </Rectangle.Width>
          </Rectangle>
        </Grid> <!-- End of Header grid -->

        <ItemsPresenter Grid.Row="2"/> <!-- Children -->

      </Grid> <!-- End of Main grid -->
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>

<Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <StackPanel
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
        IsItemsHost="True" 
        Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>

 <Setter Property="local:TreeViewItemBehavior.IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected"   Value="True" />

 </Style>
  </ResourceDictionary>
```

It has a couple of attached convertors with it that help with the node linking lines' creation. Also there is attached behavior that brings into view (i.e. scrolls into view) a node when it is clicked.

Here is the code behind:

```
 namespace BlogSample
{
    public class HorzLineConv : IValueConverter
    {
         public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
             TreeViewItem item = (TreeViewItem)value;
             ItemsControl ic = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(item);
             int index = ic.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(item);

             if ((string)parameter == "left")
            {
                if (index == 0) // Either left most or single item
                return (int)0;
                else
                return (int)1;
            }
            else // assume "right"
            {
                if (index == ic.Items.Count - 1)    // Either right most or single item
                return (int)0;
                else
                return (int)1;
            }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class VertLineConv : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        TreeViewItem item = (TreeViewItem)value;
        ItemsControl ic = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(item);
        int index = ic.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(item);

        if ((string)parameter == "top")
        {
            if (ic is TreeView)
                return 0;
            else
                return 1;
        }
        else // assume "bottom"
        {
            if (item.HasItems == false)
                return 0;
            else
                return 1;
        }
        }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public static class TreeViewItemBehavior
{
    #region IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected

    public static bool GetIsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected(TreeViewItem treeViewItem)
    {
        return (bool)treeViewItem.GetValue(IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected(TreeViewItem treeViewItem, bool value)
    {
        treeViewItem.SetValue(IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(TreeViewItemBehavior),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedChanged));

    static void OnIsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedChanged(DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeViewItem item = depObj as TreeViewItem;
        if (item == null)
            return;

        if (e.NewValue is bool == false)
            return;

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            item.Selected += OnTreeViewItemSelected;
        else
            item.Selected -= OnTreeViewItemSelected;
    }

    static void OnTreeViewItemSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Only react to the Selected event raised by the TreeViewItem
        // whose IsSelected property was modified.  Ignore all ancestors
        // who are merely reporting that a descendant's Selected fired.
        if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(sender, e.OriginalSource))
            return;
        //Point relativePoint = (sender as TreeViewItem).TransformToAncestor(Application.Current.MainWindow)
        //              .Transform(new Point(0, 0));

        TreeViewItem item = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;
        if (item != null)
            item.BringIntoView();
    }

    #endregion // IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected
}
}
```

What I want to do is:

Make just the parent of leaf nodes scroll horizontall into view when there is a scroll change. So that even if out of all leaf nodes (of a parent) if only 1 leaf node is visible then the parent is still visible. If all the leaf nodes of a parent go out of view then that parent node must also go out of view.

Please guide me hpow to do this. Can it be done using attached behavior? Can it be done easily using Blend?